# PC sudden shutdown, Sensors show normal temps, Thermal event interrupts shows 1276

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, shutdown

I'm experiencing sudden shutdowns on my Linux systems.

- Using Ubuntu 12.04, my kernel version is 3.5.0-37-generic #58~precise1-Ubuntu.
- Running a Acer M5 581t(G) with 6 gigs ram laptop. I have been experiencing this for more then two weeks.

Its shuts off all a sudden with no warning. The temperatures are listed below at shut off. I have Windows 8 on the same machine and no problems running Windows, no shut off. Only once, and I had to update the BIOS firmware.

```
$sensors
    Physical id 0:  +51.0°C
    Core 0:         +52.0°C
    Core 1:         +45.0°C
```

My current `/proc/interrupts` shows my Thermal event interrupts as follows:

```
TRM:        1277       1278       1276       1276   Thermal event interrupt
```

There is **no** indication in `syslog` that a request to shutdown has been issued.

What could be the cause of this behavior?

I've attached links below to my `dmesg` log, `/proc/interrupts`, system log, and kernlog. I had two unexplained shut downs at roughly 12:24 and 12:26. both back to back. The first one occured right after I opened the lid after it being closed. The other was during boot-up to recover from the first crash.

#### Included logs

- [System log](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2qsVwyt_xNVX2NmMURVa3RZSWc/edit?usp=sharing)
- [/procs/interrupts](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2qsVwyt_xNVdHVpOEtCS2wyVDg/edit?usp=sharing)
- [dmesg log](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2qsVwyt_xNVX0pmb0s4MEJET0U/edit?usp=sharing)
- [kernlog](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2qsVwyt_xNVbk5OVXdEcTlOMUk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: you don't see any cron job schedule for this shutdown?

Comment: You should be able to find a reason under /var/log/kern.log or /var/log/syslog.log or mcelog

Comment: @Salton, thanks for the input. I added to of the logs to my question. And two more to this comment.

Here are the other two logs:
[dmesg log:] 
(https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2qsVwyt_xNVX0pmb0s4MEJET0U/edit?usp=sharing)<br>
[/procs/interrupts/:]
(https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2qsVwyt_xNVdHVpOEtCS2wyVDg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I noticed `Aug 13 12:25:46 david cron[1841]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)`